# Why is this if statement not working in sas macro?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to get back one character by calling this macro, but there is an error given when running the following code:

```
%macro getcategory(date=);

%global category;

%if %year(date) < 2002 %then %do;
%let category = A;

%mend;

%getcategory(date=1999);
```

I tried with symput but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your question with the error message you get when running your code. Meanwhile, here are some issues I have spotted:

- `%year` is not a SAS/Macro function
- If `%year` was a function, running it on `date` without using an ampersand would simply try to run it on the literal 'date'
- You have opened a `%do` block but have not concluded it with `%end`
- You are supplying a numbered date, so there is no need to convert this to a year using a function

This code should set the macro variable `category` with the value of A when you pass a number less than 2022 - hopefully this functioning code will help you towards what you're hoping to achieve:

```
%macro getcategory(date=);

%global category;

%if %eval(&date < 2002) %then %do;
  %let category = A;
%end;

%mend;

%getcategory(date=1999);
/* Added a %put statement to return the value of category */
%put &category;
```

If you are struggling with SAS Macro, you can turn on these options to help:

```
OPTIONS MPRINT MLOGIC SYMBOLGEN;
/*off: OPTIONS NOMPRINT NOMLOGIC NOSYMBOLGEN;*/
```